# LINQ .ToArray doing some additional calculations before adding the row

Tags: c#, linq

i've the following linq query

```
 foreach (var row in nodes.
      Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")
       .Select(td => td.InnerText.TrimEnd())
       .ToArray()))
{
   mydatatable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

can i add elments to the array like arthmatic calculations inside the linq syntax based on the values of other array indecies, without having to loop another time?

for example the resultant array will look like `["xx","9.4",1.4"]` , i am trying to add another elment for example the multiplication of the second element by the third elment so it will look like `["xx","9.4","2","18.8"]` and for sure its in string format, so need to cast to double then multiply then again to string

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to do without linq?

Comment: I don't see any arithmetic calculations here. Also looks like you are parsing html

Comment: Could you show an example input and output?

Comment: just update the question

Comment: First of all for every iteration you are doing the same LINQ again and again. Get it outside of the loop into a variable and use that variable in your loop.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany what do you mean with doing it again and again? this is no different from putting it outside the loop as far as i know

Comment: A note (not related to your question): you don't need the `.ToArray()` here. `foreach` works fine with the `IEnumerable` that comes out of the `.Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want an array in this situation. Consider `IList<T>` and doing these calculations outside of `LINQ` for performance, readability and access.

```
IList<int> rows = nodes.Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")).Select(td => Convert.ToInt32( td.InnerText.TrimEnd())).ToList();
rows.Add(rows[1] * rows[2]);
```

Note: I know that you perhaps don't have integers, for the purpose of example code I casted otherwise you can't multiply.

```
IList<string> strs = nodes.Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")).Select(td => td.InnerText.TrimEnd()).ToList();
var ints = strs.Select(str => str.TryGetInt()).Where(i => i.HasValue).Select(i => i.Value);
strs.Add((ints[0] * [ints[1]).ToString());

public static class Extensions
{
  public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
  {
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
  }
}
```

Comment: problem is its a mix of strings, ints and decimals

Comment: @user1590636 I have posted the alternative solution

Comment: do think this would be faster than doing another loop without using LINQ, other it looks awesome :)

Comment: @user1590636 The majority of your work is completed outside of a loop now, you just have to loop through your string values. Call `ToArray()` on it if you so wish. If you want a proper answer, please try and benchmark two different methods. The above is just to get you to where you want to go :)